# How do I use a dataframe's data in creating a aggregated column then expanding rows using another dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame that gives me funding for various products at different levels. This is a wide data frame that shows funding from 2021-Jan-01 to 2021-Dec-31 (`Funding_Start_date` and `Funding_End_Date` format `yyyyMMdd`)

```
funding_data = [
    (20210101,20211231,"Family","Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 12345, "Lump_Sum", 50000)
  ]

funding_schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("Funding_Start_Date",IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("Funding_End_Date",IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("Funding_Level",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("Type", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Brand", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Brand_Low", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Family", FloatType(), True), \
    StructField("SKU_ID", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("Allocation_Basis", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Amount", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])

funding_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=funding_data,schema=funding_schema)
funding_df.show()

+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+
|Funding_Start_Date|Funding_End_Date|Funding_Level|Type|Brand|Brand_Low|Family|SKU_ID|Allocation_Basis|Amount|
+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+
|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum|50000|
+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+
```

I want to have a row for each day of funding with a per-day `Amount` depending on the following factor:

> a sale has been made on that day at that `Funding_Level`

I have a sales table at a Date and SKU level.

```
sales_data = [
    (20210105,352210,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 1),
    (20210106,352207,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 5),
    (20210106,352196,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 2),
    (20210109,352212,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 3),
    (20210112,352212,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 1),
    (20210112,352212,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 2),
    (20210112,352212,"Cars","BMW","X6", 325.0, 2),
    (20210126,352196,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 1),
    

  ]

sales_schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("DATE_ID",IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("SKU_ID",IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("Type",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("Brand", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Brand_Low", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Family", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("Quantity", IntegerType(), True)
  ])

sales_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=sales_data,schema=sales_schema)
sales_df.show()

+--------+------+----+-----+---------+------+--------+
| DATE_ID|SKU_ID|Type|Brand|Brand_Low|Family|Quantity|
+--------+------+----+-----+---------+------+--------+
|20210105|352210|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0|       1|
|20210106|352207|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0|       5|
|20210106|352196|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0|       2|
|20210109|352212|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0|       3|
|20210112|352212|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0|       1|
|20210112|352212|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0|       2|
|20210112|352212|Cars|  BMW|       X6| 325.0|       2|
|20210126|352196|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0|       1|
+--------+------+----+-----+---------+------+--------+
```

This would tell me there are 5 unique days when a Product with a column `Family` of 420.0 has been sold.

```
sales_df.filter(col('Family') == 420.0).select('DATE_ID').distinct().show()

+--------+
| DATE_ID|
+--------+
|20210112|
|20210109|
|20210105|
|20210106|
|20210126|
+--------+
```

So the `Lumpsum/Day` would be 50000/5 = 10000

So I'm trying to get a final data frame like this:

```
+--------+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+-----------+
| DATE_ID|Funding_Start_Date|Funding_End_Date|Funding_Level|Type|Brand|Brand_Low|Family|SKU_ID|Allocation_Basis|Amount|Lumpsum/Day|
+--------+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+-----------+
|20210105|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum| 50000|      10000|
+--------+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+-----------+
|20210106|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum| 50000|      10000|
+--------+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+-----------+
|20210109|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum| 50000|      10000|
+--------+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+-----------+
|20210112|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum| 50000|      10000|
+--------+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+-----------+
|20210126|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum| 50000|      10000|
+--------+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+-----------+
```

I've tried UDF's but I wasn't able to pass the `sales_df` in it to count the days and divide it by the `Lump_Sum` amount as UDF's don't accept data frames.

How do I get to this final data frame from the above two data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the `Lumpsum/Day` per `family` and `Funding_Start_Date` and `Funding_End_Date`:

1. Convert the `Funding_Start_Date`, `Funding_End_Date` and `DATE_ID` to `DateType`.
2. Select distinct `DATE_ID` and `Family` from `sales_df`.
3. Join `funding_df` and `sales_df` such that the `DATE_ID` is between `Funding_Start_Date` and `Funding_End_Date` and the `Family` are same.
4. Apply `count` window aggregation over `Funding_Start_Date`, `Funding_End_Date` and `Family` to find number of days with sales.
5. Divide `Amount` with result from step 4 to arrive at `Lumpsum/Day`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

funding_data = [
    (20210101,20211231,"Family","Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 12345, "Lump_Sum", 50000)
  ]

funding_schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("Funding_Start_Date",IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("Funding_End_Date",IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("Funding_Level",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("Type", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Brand", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Brand_Low", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Family", FloatType(), True), \
    StructField("SKU_ID", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("Allocation_Basis", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Amount", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])

funding_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=funding_data,schema=funding_schema)

# STEP 1
funding_df = (funding_df.withColumn("Funding_Start_Date", F.to_date(F.col("Funding_Start_Date").cast("string"), "yyyyMMdd"))
                        .withColumn("Funding_End_Date", F.to_date(F.col("Funding_End_Date").cast("string"), "yyyyMMdd")))

sales_data = [
    (20210105,352210,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 1),
    (20210106,352207,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 5),
    (20210106,352196,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 2),
    (20210109,352212,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 3),
    (20210112,352212,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 1),
    (20210112,352212,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 2),
    (20210112,352212,"Cars","BMW","X6", 325.0, 2),
    (20210126,352196,"Cars","Audi","A4", 420.0, 1),
    

  ]

sales_schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("DATE_ID",IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("SKU_ID",IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("Type",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("Brand", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Brand_Low", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Family", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("Quantity", IntegerType(), True)
  ])

sales_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=sales_data,schema=sales_schema)

# STEP 1
sales_df = sales_df.withColumn("DATE_ID", F.to_date(F.col("DATE_ID").cast("string"), "yyyyMMdd"))

# STEP 2
sales_df = sales_df.select("DATE_ID", "Family").distinct()

# STEP 3
joined_df = funding_df.join(sales_df, (sales_df["DATE_ID"].between(funding_df["Funding_Start_Date"], funding_df["Funding_End_Date"]) & (funding_df["Family"] == sales_df["Family"])))
joined_df = joined_df.select(*[funding_df[c] for c in funding_df.columns], "DATE_ID")

# STEP 4 and 5
ws = Window.partitionBy("Funding_Start_Date", "Funding_End_Date", "Family").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

(joined_df.withColumn("Lumpsum/Day", F.col("amount") / (F.count("DATE_ID").over(ws)))
          .withColumn("Funding_Start_Date", F.date_format("Funding_Start_Date", "yyyyMMdd").cast("int"))
          .withColumn("Funding_End_Date", F.date_format("Funding_End_Date", "yyyyMMdd").cast("int"))
          .withColumn("DATE_ID", F.date_format("DATE_ID", "yyyyMMdd").cast("int"))
).show()
```

#### Output

```
+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+--------+-----------+
|Funding_Start_Date|Funding_End_Date|Funding_Level|Type|Brand|Brand_Low|Family|SKU_ID|Allocation_Basis|Amount| DATE_ID|Lumpsum/Day|
+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+--------+-----------+
|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum| 50000|20210106|    10000.0|
|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum| 50000|20210112|    10000.0|
|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum| 50000|20210126|    10000.0|
|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum| 50000|20210105|    10000.0|
|          20210101|        20211231|       Family|Cars| Audi|       A4| 420.0| 12345|        Lump_Sum| 50000|20210109|    10000.0|
+------------------+----------------+-------------+----+-----+---------+------+------+----------------+------+--------+-----------+
```